# How can I submit an array of checkboxes such that there is one (but only one) value for each element in the array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I execute a SQL statement in my controller:

```
@lots = execute_statement("select date_trunc ('day', filled_at) as Fill_Date, shift_id, count(id) from liquor_lots where available = true group by date_trunc ('day', filled_at), shift_id order by Fill_Date")
```

In my view, I iterate through the rows of the resultset, and generate an array of each element

```
<%= form_with(url: add_path, method: "post") do |form| %>
<% @lots.each do |row| %>
    
    <tr>
        <td><%= form.text_field :fill_date, value:row['fill_date'], name: "fill_date[]" %></td>
        
        <td><%= form.text_field :shift_id, value:row['shift_id'], name: "shift_id[]" %></td>
        
        <td><%= form.check_box :all_pallets, name: "all_pallets[]"  %></td>
        
    </tr>
```

I need to perform logic on the first two parameters (`fill_date` and `shift_id`) if the checkbox is selected.  So my plan is to go through `all_pallets` parameter and if it is selected, I will access the data in the other arrays using the index.

Controller:

```
  all_pallets = params["all_pallets"]
  filled_dates = params["fill_date"]
  shift_ids = params["shift_id"]
  all_pallets.each_with_index do |pallet, index|
       #pseudo-code
       if pallet is selected, perform logic based on filled_dates[index] and shift_ids[index]
```

My issue is that if I use `check_box`, I get a '0' for every checkbox plus a '1' for all the checked boxes.
If I use `check_box_tag`, I only get a '1' for the selected rows and no elements for the unchecked boxes.
I need to have 0's for the unchecked and 1's for the checked, but the total number of elements in the array need to match the other arrays.

Example, if my original query returned 5 rows and I checked 2 of the boxes:

with `check_box_tag`, params =  `"...shift_id"=>["2", "1", "1", "2", "3"], "all_pallets"=>["1", "1"],`

with `check_box`, params =  `"...shift_id"=>["2", "1", "1", "2", "3"], "all_pallets"=>["0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0"]`

and what I need is `"...shift_id"=>["2", "1", "1", "2", "3"], "all_pallets"=>["0", "1", "0", "1", "0"]`

How can this be done?

Comment: I think you can try `form.check_box :all_pallets, {}, "true", "false"`. Check the console in the browser to see that the proper inputs are been created.

Comment: Generating the inputs is not the problem.  It's the parameters that are submitted that I can't get right.